# How do I change the \mathtt font with mathspec?

Tags: fonts, typewriter, mathspec

I have a document where the main font is Gotham Narrow Book but the numbers are set in Gotham Narrow Light, and this is set with commands provided by the [`mathspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathspec) package.  I'd like to typeset a table where the digits come from a monospace font so that they'll line up better.  But my invocation of `\setmathtt` has no effect.

Here is my sample document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont[BoldFont=Gotham Narrow Medium]{Gotham Narrow Book}
\setmathrm{Gotham Book}
\setmathfont(Latin){Gotham Narrow Book}
\setmathfont(Digits){Gotham Narrow Light}
%:FIXME seems to have no effect
\setmathtt{Courier} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
 Normal         & TT \\
 $123456789$ & $\mathtt{123456789}$ \\
 $111111111$ & $\mathtt{111111111}$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Does `\setmathfont(Digits){Gotham Narrow Light}` preclude `\setmathtt{Courier}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in mathspec; if I ask for

```
\showthe\mathcode`1
```

I get `1841`, i.e., `"0731`. It seems that `7` is the math group for Gotham Narrow Light, so the mathcode should be `"7731`. Indeed, if I say

```
\mathcode`\0=\numexpr\mathcode`0+"7000\relax
\mathcode`\1=\numexpr\mathcode`1+"7000\relax
\mathcode`\2=\numexpr\mathcode`2+"7000\relax
\mathcode`\3=\numexpr\mathcode`3+"7000\relax
\mathcode`\4=\numexpr\mathcode`4+"7000\relax
\mathcode`\5=\numexpr\mathcode`5+"7000\relax
\mathcode`\6=\numexpr\mathcode`6+"7000\relax
\mathcode`\7=\numexpr\mathcode`7+"7000\relax
\mathcode`\8=\numexpr\mathcode`8+"7000\relax
\mathcode`\9=\numexpr\mathcode`9+"7000\relax
```

I get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It works with `\setmathtt{Courier New}` and something like `\mathtt{f(x)}` because the digits are set with Gotham.

Comment: But that's the problem Matthew is describing.  It seems like when you specify a math font for digits, using `\setmathsfont` that gets used no matter how you specify the `mathtt` font.

Comment: I know, what's the problem ...

Comment: Matthew wants his `mathtt` digits to be in the `mathtt` font.  That's the problem.

Comment: @Alan: I wrote that I know the problem ...

Comment: Sorry, a little German/English linguistic mix-up there. Your comma after 'know' and the verb second in 'what's the problem' made me think that 'what's the problem' was a question.  (But now I definitely don't understand your posted answer.)